# Where is the Alfresco audit log?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

```
curl -u id:pw "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/audit/query/testapp?verbose=true&limit=200&forward=false"
```

Where is the Alfresco audit log that could be run by the above command actually stored?
I thought it was somewhere in the database but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Auditing_(from_V3.4):

- **alf_audit_model**: Audit configuration files are recorded here.
- **alf_audit_application**: An entry for each logical application. There may be several audit applications defined in a single audit model.
- **alf_audit_entry**: Each call to AuditComponent.recordAuditValues will result in an entry here. There is a reference to a property.